# Multi-processing with generators reading from multiple files as input for keras

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing, generator

I am training a neural network with keras and want to speed up my pre-processing/data augmentation via multi-processing. In principle, this seems straightforward with `workers=N` and `use_multiprocessing=True` in the `fit_generator`, but in my situation it is tricky to avoid getting similar data from the parallel generators.

My data is in several files, each with a few million records (total not known until you reach the end of a file). For each file the generator goes record by record, processes the record into the correct input/output format for the network with some data augmentation. There is no unique ID, although I guess I could create one on-the-fly.

I wondered whether it would be easiest to have multiple generators in parallel that each deal with a separate lists of files. I don't actually use all data in a batch, so it would not really matter if one generator re-starts at the start of its file list before the others. If within the generator I could access something like a worker-number (1 to N), that would be easily done.

Comment: Do you have your data as `TFRecords`, or as pure text files?

Comment: Text. My generator does data augmentation + encoding it into a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to implement what you propose. A more high-level solution would be to instantiate a `tf.data.TextLineDataset`, which can handle multiple text files. In order to train a Keras model with this, you have to tie the output of the `iterator` to the `Input` tensor of your model. Something along these lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
# Parsing, augmentation etc
def __parse_record(record):
    ...
    return parsed_record

# Construct a TextLineDataset
ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames).map(_parse_record)
ds.shuffle().batch(batch_size) # Shuffle and batch

# Turn into an iterator
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(ds.output_types, ds.output_shapes)
ds_init = iterator.make_initializer(ds)
# The iterator will yield inputs and labels
x,y = iterator.get_next()

# Tie output of iterator into Input of keras model via the tensor argument
model_input = Input(tensor=x)
# ... model definition

# Upon compiling the model specify target tensors
model.compile(loss, optimizer, target_tensors=[y])

# Now you can use model.fit() instead of fit_generator()
with K.get_session() as sess:
    sess.run(ds_init)
    model.fit(epochs, steps_per_epoch)
```

This should train quite fast, however, it brings some disadvantages. According to the relevant [Keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_tfrecord.py):

> Input Tensors also have important disadvantages. In
>   particular, Input Tensors are fixed at model construction
>   because rewiring networks is not yet supported.
>   For this reason, changing the data input source means
>   model weights must be saved and the model rebuilt
>   from scratch to connect the new input data.
>   validation cannot currently be performed as training
>   progresses, and must be performed after training completes.